# Screen Reader Placeholder Issue

Tags: html, screen-readers

I am currently working on accessibility for a form and have come across an issue with placeholder on an input textbox. The HTML of the input is

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100" size="40" id="p_email" name="Contact::ContactEmail" />
```

Upon testing this with a screen read extension on Chrome ([ChromeVox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en)), the text being read out appears to sound like:

> Email address within Email address [pause for 1 second] Edit Text

If I remove the placeholder attribute, the text being read out becomes:

> Email address [pause for 1 second] Edit text

- So is there any way to make the screen reader not take the
  `placeholder` attribute into consideration?
- Also, can I make the screen reader not say "Edit text" at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChromeVox is a handy developer tool, but most users who need a screen reader use JAWS or NVDA.  Each screen reading tool may treat placeholders differently and how and if it's read can depend on your markup especially labelling on both sides.

Ideally you should use a label along with aria-labelledby on the input even if that label is positioned off screen.

"Edit text" is an indication to the user that they are able to edit the text, you DO NOT want to alter this functionality.

```
<label id="the-email-label" for="p_email">Email Address</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100" size="40" id="p_email" name="Contact::ContactEmail" aria-labelledby="the-email-label"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had this sorted out already as suggested by you, had used the `aria-labelledby` attribute. So I'll mark this as solved in case someone else is looking for a solution to this.